# Laravel route showing "Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following the following tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_middleware.htm

I'm on Step 9, and I'm getting a "404 | Not Found" error. Here's my exact code:

> app\Http\routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/role',[
    'middleware' => 'Role:editor',
    'uses' => 'TestController@index',
]);
```

> app\Http\Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
           // \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'Age' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
        'Role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

> app\Http\Controllers\TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        echo "<br>Test Controller.";
    }
}
```

> app\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role) {
        echo "Role: ".$role;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss at this point, as to why it would give me a 404. Looking up some other questions here on SO, I'd thought it was because the Route had `role` and not `/role`, but that change did nothing. I even did the following route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

And received a 404 as well. I created my project in PHPStorm, and as a "Composer Project" and used the package `laravel/installer`.

Comment: Did you created welcome view in the views folder?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou: The `welcome` view was created by default when I created the project.

Comment: Did you check main url to view welcome page?

Comment: localhost:8000/ -> shows the welcome view?

Comment: Yes, I did. `Welcome` view shows just fine

Comment: You should have in views folder, a folder with name test and inside an index view.It would be better if you could show the dir structure with files and folders.

Comment: What does the error log say? You can access it in ```/laravel-project-folder/storage/logs/```

Comment: Are you using an update-to-date version of Laravel? The steps described in the tutorial are not really meant to be used in newer (5.7 / 5.8) versions of laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was adding the route to `app\Http\routes.php`. The latest version of Laravel actually has web routes in `routes/web.php`. Adding my route there solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please try using php artisan then report back with the result.